# 2 GET routes to same Resource in Flask-RESTful

Tags: python, rest, flask-restful

I am learning Flask-RESTful and I have the following task i want to do:

There are these 2 GET Routes

GET /student/id (get student details, search student by ID)
GET /student/id/grades (get student grades, search student by ID)

If i don't want to have if statement in student GET function, how can I have this implemented?
I must create 2 different resources? Student and GradesList?

Thanks, Alon

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should create 2 different resources as follows:

```
from flask_restful import Api

api = Api(app)

class StudentResource(Resource):

    def get(self, id):
        // Your code here. This is an example
        student = Student.get(id)

class GradeListResource(Resource):

    def get(self, id):
        // Your code here. This is an example
        student = Student.get(id)
        grades = studen.grades()

api.add_resource(StudentResource, '/student/<int:id>', endpoint='student_resource')
api.add_resource(GradeListResource, '/student/<int:id>/grades', endpoint='grade_list_resource')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order to

```
/student/id/grades

/student/id
```

The error happens because route searching happens in the order in which you list them.

For eg. say you have two routes as follows:
`/a/b` and `/a/`
Let's consider two cases -

**Order 1**

/a/

/a/b/

Now if you search for `/a/<some id>` then it matches the first route and you are routed accordingly. Again, when you search for `/a/b/<some id>`, the prefix i.e. `/a/` matches again and you are routed to the first route.

**Order 2**-

/a/b/

/a/

Now, if you search for `/a/<some id>` then it does not match the first route (as the prefix `/a/b/` does not match). But the second route matches and you are  routed accordingly.As an alternative, if you search for `/a/b/<some id>` then the first route matches. And then you are routed to the correct URL.

As a rule of thumb, remember to put the more particular case first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is about how to build the resources. I don't have error. My question is if and how can have multiple GET function for student resource. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure, You need to create 2 different resources since the second GET in the same Resource class will override the first one.

However, you can still take use of simple Flask API rather than flask_restful.
You may find this thread useful:[Using basic Flask vs Flask-RESTful for API development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777537/using-basic-flask-vs-flask-restful-for-api-development)

and more importantly, this: [Flask RESTful API multiple and complex endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715238/flask-restful-api-multiple-and-complex-endpoints?rq=1)