# Flask Restul default parameter

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to specify an optional parameter to my flask restful api.

I have the following route defined where mode is optional.

My **route** is defined like so

```
api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/<id>/<mode>")
```

My **controller** is defined like so:

```
class TestController(Resource):
    def get(
        self,
        id: int,
        mode: int = -1,
    ):
```

I read one way to do it is like so

```
api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/<id>/")
api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/<id>/<mode>")
```

But this causes an error for me and gives me :
`AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: loggers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points I would change here.

1. Remove the trailing / from the first declaration:

   api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/")
2. Add expected types to the get parameters e.g.:

   api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/int:id")
   api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/int:id/int:mode")
3. I wouldn't associate two different routes with the same class.

class TestController1(Resource):
def get(
self,
id: int,
):

class TestController2(Resource):
def get(
self,
id: int,
mode: int = -1
):

Then change your routes correspondingly.

If you must do so, then it's better to write the route like this:

```
api.add_resource(TestController, "/test/<int:id>", "/test/<int:id>/<int:mode>")
```

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715238/flask-restful-api-multiple-and-complex-endpoints) might be of use